# Is this question ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases

The following multiple-choice question was asked in an exam:

> **Which one is the internal storage device that performs better than its predecessor with spinning disks inside?**
>
> - HDD
> - SSD
> - USB flash drive
> - RAM

I wonder if the question is ambiguous in regards to what *with spinning disks inside* modifies in it.

**Edit:** As Prof. Shor had assumed, my main concern here really is whether *with spinning disks inside* can be thought of as a modifier to what is being asked, and not to the predecessor; ultimately making HDD the answer.

Comment: Please clarify. I assume you're asking what *with spinning disks inside* modifies.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, and I am mainly interested in that. However, I would also be interested if there exists just about any other ambiguities there is. I will edit the question in accordance with my main interest, regardless.

Comment: I'm sure they want you to pick *SSD*, but there's nothing technically incorrect about [*RAM*](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-use-ram-as-hard-drive-how-to-create-ramdisk/), which is the fastest type of storage. (There also *is* [nonvolatile RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory)—such as ferroelectric RAM or the latest magnetoresistive RAM, even though the umbrella acronym for it is *NVRAM* or *NVM*.) Even from a technical perspective, it's a poorly worded question.

Comment: As for the actual question, I might rephrase it as *than its predecessor **which had** spinning disks inside*. (Even though the technology still exists.) Or possibly (if you don't like that tense) *than its **spinning-disk-based** predecessor*.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's ambiguous. You do need to have a bit of techy knowledge to be sure but that seems to be what they're testing anyway, so it's fair enough. The question can't be asking for a device with a spinning disk because that could only be the HDD, and none of the other devices are predecessors of the HDD that have inferior performance - so you are looking for an internal device that was developed after the HDD, can be used as a replacement for a HDD, and performs better - that can only be the SSD.

Comment: @Minty I couldn't follow the reasoning behind "the question can't be asking for a device with a spinning disk because that could only be the HDD".

Comment: Actually, an HDD is faster than it's predecessor, a large cabinet with disks (spools) of magnetic tape spinning back and forth.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I meant that if the question is interpreted as meaning *which one is an internal storage device that performs better than its predecessor and has spinning disks inside* the answer could only be the HDD, because none of the other devices have spinning disks - but at the same time the HDD is not a device that performs better than its predecessor, so that interpretation makes the question unanswerable, and can't be right. If you consider the alternative interpretation (it's the predecessor that has spinning disks) the answer is clear.

Comment: @HotLicks yes that's true, and the question doesn't say explicitly that the predecessor has to be in the list, but I think the implication is clear enough.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the multiple-choice question. And the answer is SSD. "[W]ith spinning disks inside" refers to "its predecessor" (only). If not, it would have be placed somewhere else in the sentence.

Comment: @Minty, I think the same as Hot Licks and do not agree that there is a clear implication about the predecessor being on the list in the question. I believe the question wouldn't become invalid if *Microphone* was written in place of the *HDD*.

Comment: Well, that would be a different question. There would then be no devices with spinning disks in the list, so it would be clear that it was the predecessor that had spinning disks. I don't think the fact that the reader has to use some real-world knowlege to decide between linguistically possible interpretations is enough to make a question ambiguous. We do this all the time without even noticing it. Here you have some sort of IT test taking about one internal storage device being a predecessor of another (with spinning disks), then you have SSD and HDD...

Comment: I'm sorry if you dropped a mark but I honestly think it's fair to expect candidates to recover the intended meaning. Also note that if the predecessor does not have to be in the list, there would be more than one correct answer, which is a pretty strong indication that it does have to be.

Comment: @Minty Thank you for the relief and sympathy. I also simply expected them to choose SSD against HDD, but seeing that a sizeable proportion did choose HDD, I cannot help considering to grant some for that answer, too, and seeking a reasonable basis to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it seems to be ambiguous. "with spinning disks inside" could modify "internal storage device", "performs better", or "predecessor".

However, to someone at all familiar with the devices (the presumed audience for the question), the first two interpretations make little sense. Only one of the listed devices has spinning disks inside, but those interpretations seem to assume that they all do. And if a device can't have spinning disks inside, it's not reasonable to ask if it performs better with spinning disks inside.

The last interpretation does make sense. All the devices have predecessors, and some of those predecessors have spinning disks inside. It's reasonable then to ask which one performs better.

So by process of elimination, only the last interpretation is likely. Also, it's generally common to resolve this ambiguity by choosing the closest preceding phrase for which the prepositional phrase is applicable.